# Observable Data Service

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a problem with data service and I think that everyone has encounter this problem !
What I want to acheive is to make a data service that update the view when data arrives!
In other word I am in the first page then I load the data from the source to list it, and then I click on the button "add new data" to add new item and post to the server when I go back, the view does not take back this effect and I have to make hard refersh to list the new item

```
  export class WorkoutPage implements OnInit{
  workouts:WorkoutModel[];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.workoutservice.doRefersh();
  }
  constructor(private workoutservice:WorkoutService,
              public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.workoutservice.workoutsList
      .subscribe(worklist => {
        console.log("GET WORKOUTS");
        this.workouts = worklist;
      });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }
  workoutSelected(evt,w) {
    this.navCtrl.push(WorkoutDetailPage, {
      workout:w
    })
  }
}
```

The Data Service

```
@Injectable()
export class WorkoutService{
  workoutsList:BehaviorSubject<WorkoutModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<WorkoutModel[]>([]);
  apiKey:string;
  apiUrl:string;
  constructor(private _http:Http) {
    console.log("Service connected");
    this.apiKey="**************************";
    this.apiUrl="*****;
  }
  doRefersh() {
    console.log("doRefersh");
    this._http.get(this.apiUrl+this.apiKey)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("qs=>"+res.json());
        this.workoutsList.next(<WorkoutModel[]>res.json());
      });
  }
  addWorkout(workout) {
    let mheaders = new Headers();
    mheaders.append('Content-type','application/json');
    let options: RequestOptionsArgs =
    {
      headers : mheaders
    };

    return this._http.post(this.apiUrl+this.apiKey,
      JSON.stringify(workout),options).map( res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Ionic Tab Pages

```
export class TabsPage {

  tabListWorkouts = WorkoutPage;
  tabAddWorkout = AddWorkoutPage;
  tabAbout = AboutPage;
  constructor() {

  }
}

<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabListWorkouts" tabTitle="Workouts" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabAddWorkout" tabTitle="Add Workout" tabIcon="add"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabAbout" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: you must use `state management` using store concepts in reactive programming.

Comment: Thanks for u reply. do u mean that i have to use ngrx store to share data state between component?

Comment: Yup. That's the best approach in case of multiple and components at various levels